# Facebook's "Messaging an Open Graph message" functionality keeps on returning to my app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying out Facebook's new [Messaging an Open Graph message](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/message-dialog/), which means one can now send open graph stories to friends via the Facebook Messenger app.

In my case, I am building an app where people *create* a *playlist* and can then invite others to contribute songs to that said playlists. Therefore, an interesting path to take is being able to post an open graph message via Facebook Messenger to one's friends.

I have set up a **Create** action, a **Playlist** object and a **Create a Playlist** story.

The code I use in the iOS app is very close to the one provided as an example by Facebook:

Creating the playlist object:

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *object =
[FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"vibe-social-music:playlist"
                                        title:@"Sample Playlist"
                                        image:@"https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png"
                                          url:@"http://samples.ogp.me/616101581814728"
                                  description:@""];
```

Creating the action:

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *action = [FBGraphObject graphObject];
action[@"playlist"] = object;
```

Creating the params:

```
FBOpenGraphActionParams *params = [[FBOpenGraphActionParams alloc]
                                   initWithAction:action
                                   actionType:@"create"
                                   previewPropertyName:@"playlist"];
```

Calling the 'present message' dialog within the messenger app:

```
[FBDialogs
 presentMessageDialogWithOpenGraphActionParams:params
 clientState:nil
 handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         //TODO: Handle errors
         NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
     } else {
         NSLog(@"results: %@", results);
     }
 }];
```

As I explained before, the Facebook messenger app opens, but quickly returns back to my application.

I have the Facebook credentials well setup in my Info.plist file.

The one thing is that the action is not yet validated by Facebook. Could that be an issue?

Otherwise, I'm at a loss as to why it won't show an Open Graph story in the Messenger app, and why it always goes back to my application.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm you configured a custom story in the Open Graph section of your app settings (and not just the action and object types)?

Also, it looks like the action type is missing your app namespace in the `params` construction: i.e.,

```
FBOpenGraphActionParams *params = [[FBOpenGraphActionParams alloc]
                               initWithAction:action
                               actionType:@"vibe-social-music:create"
                               previewPropertyName:@"playlist"];
```

Comment: Yes, there is a custom story implemented in the Open Graph. Could you provide with a code example of where the actionType@"namespace:action" should appear? In what way is the actionType different from the action?

Comment: The action type in your snippet where you create the FBOpenGraphActionParams instance. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: thanks; could you also tell me if the action (and open-graph story) needs to be public/approved by Facebook? Or should this story work even if it's only on the testing environment? Would only the "tester" users be able to see it in its integrity?

Comment: Your app will need to be public and the open graph story will need to be approved before you launch the app publicly. Until then, only users that have been assigned as developers/testers to the app will be able to see it.

Comment: so, I have changed the code to what you suggested `actionType:@"vibe-social-music:create"`; another person is the tester for the app; BUT, the application still goes to Facebook Messenger and before I can even select the people I will send the story to, it goes back into my app. Any other ideas?

Comment: Alright, it's fixed. It was also partly related to the namespace.